# What does small white arrow on battery charge indicator mean?

Tags: death-stranding

This white mark:

[image]

And for another vehicle it's on other half, so it's not some kind of percentage:

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Please post answers as answers rather than in comments.

Answer (score 2):

In Death Stranding the vehicles operate on rechargeable batteries instead of oil. The indicator in your picture shows just that. It is an indicator for the battery charge of the vehicle.

[Usgamer](https://www.reddit.com/r/DeathStranding/comments/e2bavc/anyone_know_what_the_white_mark_at_around_66_on/) has an informative description about the whole battery draining process if you are interested.

So it seems that after more research, it turns out the arrow is the additional power indicator, as explained in this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DeathStranding/comments/e2bavc/anyone_know_what_the_white_mark_at_around_66_on/). From this site the more in-depth explanation: "I think everything to the right of that mark is your suit's back up battery. If you equip more batteries to your bag the meter gets longer but the white mark stays in that spot".

Comment: Your answer should include what exactly that indicator does. It is not an indicator for half the charge (that is the double points)

Comment: so backpack battery affect vehicles? that sounds a bit strange

Comment: Yes, pretty much seems so.